# Difference between 1d and 2d arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

```
 int arr[3][2]={{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
 int *c=&arr;
 for(i=0;i<3;i++)
 {
      for(j=0;j<2;j++)
      {
          printf("\n %d %d",((arr+i)+j),*(*(arr+i)+j));
      }             
 }
 for(i=0;i<6;i++)
 {
      printf("\n%d",(c++));
 }

output:
 2293536 1
 2293536 2
 2293552 3
 2293552 4
 2293568 5
 2293568 6

 2293536
 2293540
 2293544
 2293548
 2293552
```

I cannot understand this: why one dimensional array is not same as 2d? Both are stored like linear array. `arr[1][0]` is not same as `(arr+0)+1`. why address are different in `arr`?

Comment: Please indent your code ! Where is the problem ? What do you expect ?

Comment: `arr[0][1]` is the same as `(arr+0)+1`.

Comment: For treating a 1D array as a rectangular 2D array, indexing is `(y*width) + x`.

Comment: @hivert Shall not it be the same as `*(*(arr+0)+1)`?

Comment: @Sneftel Apologies, you're correct.

Comment: `printf("\n %d %d",(c++));` You've got two format specifiers, but you're only supplying one value.

Comment: 2d stored like linear array it has one address every block. what is column represent does it have address

Comment: Notice that you have `*(arr+i) + j` in one expression and `(arr+i)+j` == `(arr + i + j)` in the other. The pointer `*arr` is an `int *` and so advances in 4 byte units like `c`. But `arr` will advance in units of 2 (length of your inner array) * 4 bytes. These are different pointers with different properties ...

Answer (score 2):

`arr[1][0]` is not the same as `(arr+0)+1` - it was never supposed to be. `arr[1][0]` is equivalent to `*(*(arr+1)+0)`, or, if you mean the address, then `&arr[1][0]` is the same as `*(arr+1)+0`.

Thus, your `printf` is wrong:

```
printf("\n %d %d",((arr+i)+j),*(*(arr+i)+j));
```

Remember, since `arr` is a 3 by 2 array, `arr+x` is `2*sizeof(int)` bytes away. Because of that, you are printing addresses that don't match what you dereference. `arr+i+j` is not the address of `*(*(arr+i)+j)`.

If you want to print the address followed by what is in there, you should use this instead:

```
printf("\n %p %d", (void *) *(arr+i)+j,*(*(arr+i)+j));
```

Note the format specifier `%p`. It must be `*(arr+i)+j`, and not `(arr+i)+j`, because `*(arr+i)` is of type `int *` - it's a pointer to the first element in `arr[i]`.

Your second `printf` call:

```
printf("\n %d %d",(c++));
```

Is invalid: you specify two format specifiers and provide only one.