# why two dimensional is not equal to one dimemsional

Tags: c, arrays

`a[6]={1,2,3,4,5,6};`

memory layout for a

```
       1     2    3    4    5    6 
addr   2002  2006 2010 2014 2016 2020
```

`b[2][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6};`

memory layout for b

```
     1     2    3    4    5    6 
addr 2002  2006 2010 2014 2016 2020
```

both a and b are same

why `a[1]` address is `2006` and `b[1]` address is `2010` both are different. arrays are stored contiguously why they are different. So I have doubt what is `braket[][]` in array we know that memory consist of address not columns and rows.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you be more clear pls?

Comment: address of one dimensional array for a[1] is not same as two dimensional array b[1]

Comment: Again?! Come on, seriously? You asked this hours ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953952/difference-between-1d-and-2d-arrays-in-c

Answer (score 3):

The answer lies in the type of what results. Almost whenever an array is mentioned in C, it decays into a pointer to its first element. Now for your two cases:

- The type of a is `int ()[6]` which decays into a pointer to int `int*` before doing the pointer arithmetic implied by `a[1]`. The expression `a[1]` is precisely equivalent to `*(a + 1)`. This pointer addition will advance the pointer by one `int`, because that is what the pointer points at.
- The type of b is `int ()[2][3]` which decays into a pointer to an array `int (*)[3]`. The size of the array that the pointer points at is three integers. As such, `*(b + 1)` advances the pointer by three integers.

Answer (score 1):

For the second array, the memory layout is actually

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| b[0][0] | b[0][1] | b[0][2] | b[1][0] | b[1][1] | b[1][2] |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Did you understand what is that he is asking? I sure didn't.

Comment: @bolov Seemed like the logical thing.

Comment: yeah you correct please specify address for every block in your answer

Comment: @srira The address is irrelevant. The *offset* though is not, and it's simply zero to five multiplied with the base type.

Comment: can you elaborate @JoachimPileborg

Comment: @srira What @JoachimPileborg is saying is that offsets go from `0*sizeof(b[0][0])` up to (and including) `5*sizeof(b[0][0])`.

Comment: @srira If the base type is `short` (assumed from your question) it's normally two bytes. That means that the offset to `b[0][1]` is two bytes from the beginning (`b[0][0]`). The last entry (`b[1][3]`) has an offset of five times two bytes from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Let's set this clear once and for all:

First, let's imagine that both `a` and `b` are mapped into the exact same memory region. That is, both `a[0]` and `b[0][0]` are stored in contiguous memory positions starting at the same address.

With this in mind, note that `a[1]` and `b[1]` are **not** the same memory location. Why? Because `a` is an array of integers, and `b` is an array of arrays of integers. Each position in `b` is an array of 3 integers; each position in `a` is an integer.

Thus, `a[1]` is not the same memory address as `b[1]`, because `b[1]` is `3*sizeof(b[0][0])` bytes away from `b[0][0]`, and `a[1]` is `sizeof(a[0])` bytes away from `a[0]`. Thus, the **offsets** are different, even though the arrays layout is the same in memory. Your confusion around `a[1]` and `b[1]` relates to the fact that the index is the same, but means different things.

`a[1]` is equivalent to `*(a+1)`, and `b[1]` is equivalent to `*(b+1)`. The thing is, `a+1` and `b+1` **scale 1 by different amounts** (again, by `sizeof(a[0])` and `3*sizeof(b[0][0])`, respectively). That's why the addresses are different.

In particular, `&b[1]` is be the same as `&a[3]`.

Comment: moreover a[1] and b[1] are not the same memory location because **they are different variables**

Comment: @bolov Right. I just put it this way because I think it's easier for the OP to understand. Good point though; I edited my answer to make this clear.